# non_field_errors : ["Expected a list of items but got type "dict"."]

Tags: python, django, angular

I create realtime chat application using websocket frontend(angular) backend(Django).. I want to store messages in to db(mySql).. when I trying to store message from angular to django.. it give me error:

```
non_field_errors:
["Expected a list of items but got type "dict"."]
```

so what is wrong?

**model.py**

```
class msg(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    receiver = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    myDate = models.DateTimeField()
```

**serializer.py**

```
class MesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=False, slug_field='name', queryset=User.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = msg
        fields = '__all__'
```

**view.py**

```
class msg_list(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        mes = msg.objects.all()
        serializer = MesSerializer(mes, many=True)  # convert into JSON
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, formate = None):
        serializer = MesSerializer(data=request.data, many = True) #type list
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Comment: you need to pass the input as this `{"name":['adrian','yousof',..],"reciever":'test","text":"something","myDate":"2018-07-05"}`

Comment: my input is passing {name: "Erika", text: "hiii", receiver: "priyal", myDate: "2018-07-25T08:56:43.510Z"}

Comment: like you said it is already passing this way

Comment: the name values has to be inside a list as slugrelatedfield requires list of items even if its single

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trouble is not with the slug. It is that you have used `many = True` in the view when you pass the data to the serializer, but you are in fact only sending a single message - which is why it is a dict and not a list. Remove that parameter.

```
def post(self, request, formate = None):
    serializer = MesSerializer(data=request.data)
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently came across a problem which is similar to the OP. Hence would like to share my experience and solution.

I have a dictionary of items, each of them unique. I wanted to use PUT to update an existing item. So I used `objects.filter` to fetch the object based on the name passed via JSON Request(I know I should have used pk, but I didn't because the items are unique and will remain so). Then I created a Django REST Serializer class object to save the updated object but I failed. This is because I wasn't using `many = True`. But when I did use it, I faced another error:

```
"non_field_errors": [
        "Expected a list of items but got type \"dict\"."
    ]
```

So I finally removed both `many=True` as well `objects.filter`.
Instead I used `objects.get`. This solved the problem because `objects.get` returns the required object which I want to update whereas `objects.filter` returns a `queryset` object and not the actual object that I want to update. Of course `objects.get` will fail if I have multiple results, in which case I need to ensure there is a pk. Then again in my case `objects.get` will never return more than one object.

Hope this post helps someone and saves a lot of their time. :-)

Comment: While giving long answers, it is better to divide it into paragraphs, make bullet points and mark your codes into CODE-FORMAT. All this makes your answer easier to read.