# Django rest Framework - Expected a list of items but got type "QuerySet"

Tags: django, django-serializer

I try to serialize query set. But Im getting **{'non_field_errors': [ErrorDetail(string='Expected a list of items but got type "QuerySet".', code='not_a_list')]}** error. How to solve this error.

```
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        user_name = data.get('username')
        signup_filtered_data = Signup.objects.filter(username= user_name).values()
        print(signup_filtered_data)
        serializer = SignupSerializer(data= signup_filtered_data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid()
        print(serializer.errors)
        signup_jason_data = json.dumps(serializer.data)
        return HttpResponse(signup_jason_data)
```

models.py

```
class Signup(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique= True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique= True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique= True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class SignupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Signup
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are trying to do here. Why *are* you passing a queryset to the serializer?

Comment: i'm trying to get row data from database this is why i used filter here and passing username, and trying to return data in json format.

Comment: But why are you using the post method if you're trying to *get* data from the database?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to get data from database.

Comment: As I said, then why are you using the post method instead of the get method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is that you have used `many = True` in the view when you pass the data to the serializer, but you are in fact only sending a single message.

```
def post(self, request, formate = None):
   serializer = SignupSerializer(data= signup_filtered_data)
```

See the actual answer:
[Actual answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51515014/6068032)

Answer (score 1):

A Much cleaner approach is using filters and serializer with a class-based view
A example of that is using **mixins**.

[Mixins DjangoRest](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/)

[FilterBackend DjangoRest](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/)

[Pagination DjangoRest](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)

[Permissions Classes DjangoRest](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/)

**filters.py**

```py
class SignupFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Signup
        fields = [
            'user_name',
        ]
```

**views.py**

```py
class YourNameView(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ] # Permission Classes
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination # Pagination Classes
    serializer_class = SignupSerializer # Your Serializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend] #This need to added on settings.py
    filter_class = SignupFilter # Your filter Class
    queryset = Signup.objects.all() 

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```